# Expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected near 'End Time'

Tags: sql, sql-server, dbfit

```
 SELECT  AgentId, StartTime, 
 EventTo =     dateadd(hh,datepart(hh,StartTime)+1,convert(datetime,convert(varchar,StartTime,112 ))),
 EndTime
 from [stage].[Agent]
 where  EndTime is not null and StartTime is not null
```

The above line will produce an error when I run within a tool called DbFit, however it will run successfully in SSMS.

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is    expected, near 'EndTime'.
```

The only way to reproduce the error in SSMS is as follows:

```
      SELECT  AgentId, StartTime, 
 EventTo =     dateadd(hh,datepart(hh,StartTime)+1,convert(datetime,convert(varchar,StartTime,112 ))),
 EndTime
 from [stage].[Agent]
 where  EndTime
```

Any ideas as to what is the issue and how to resolve it...

Comment: is stage.agent a view or a table ?

Comment: stage.agent is a table

Comment: I would imagine you have some invalid characters instead of spaces, because the syntax seems valid. Although the spaces are really spaces in the posted query

Comment: How are you running the query? Any chance you are selecting upto 'where EndTime` and running, instead of selecting the whole query? That is the only way I can reproduce the error.

Comment: Yes, I did that and I get the error. That is why I initially cut and pasted that query instead instead of the full query

Comment: So the whole query doesn't have this error, correct?

Comment: If you have a question about incorrect code, you shouldn't edit it later so that it contains correct code. That makes the question make *no* sense.

Comment: I'm going to take a guess here that your tool is truncating the query you've given it. If you run SQL profiler, what is the query that is being run?

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround more than a answer. It is existing issue with DbFit. See https://github.com/dbfit/dbfit/issues/284 for more details